# How to run systemctl --user ... after sudo?

Tags: systemd, rhel, systemctl

We've enabled `systemd --user` on our servers, and now users can manipulate their services themselves.

When a user `foo` logs-in *directly*, things like `systemctl --user status` work as expected -- `foo`'s own services are listed. So far so good.

However, when another user -- `bar` -- *switches identity* to `foo` using `sudo` (or `ksu`), the same command prints a D-BUS connection-failure error...

I suspect, some environment variable remains pointing at `bar` -- instead of `foo` -- even after the identity-change, but I cannot figure out, which one...

How do we work around this problem? Using RHEL7 here, if it matters...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615964/272848

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you!.. Now, why wouldn't `sudo` and `ksu` take care of that particular environment variable -- `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` -- and how should one deal with it?.. Sigh...