# Starting a systemd user instance for a user from a shell

Tags: linux, shell, systemd, users

I started a shell for another user on my system. However there's no systemd user instance for that user:

```
helloer@host $ sudo -u testusr bash
testusr@host $ systemctl --user status
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

How can I start a dbus or systemd user instance for testusr?

I'm running Arch Linux, linux 5.11.8.arch1-1, dbus 1.12.20-1, systemd 247.4-2.

Comment: Would `eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)` help?

Comment: Maybe... After your command, `systemctl status --user` says: `Failed to read server status: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1`

Comment: Not even root can do what  your asking.

Comment: On Debian 10, in the command 

   systemctl --user status

the --user is the owner  of /run/user/"uid", i.e., the user logged into the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615964/272848

Comment: @Stewart the answer just restates the problem. The only advice seemingly useful in the context of this question is one about `machinectl`, but running a `machinectl login archie` on my distro results in a `Failed to get login PTY: No machine 'archie' known`, and from looking at man it mentions something about containerization, so I presume it is completely irrelevant to the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do systemd stuff for another user, the simplest thing is to login as that user, eg with `ssh user@localhost`, but here is the minimal setup alternative to get a user slice running the current shell:

```
otheruser=testusr
id=$(id -u $otheruser)
sudo systemctl start user@$id
sudo -u $otheruser \
 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$id/bus \
 systemd-run --user --scope --shell
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [systemd devs](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7451#issuecomment-346787237):

> "su" is a tool for changing user identities and very few other process credentials temporarily. It's not a tool for opening a completely new login session. A new login session has a very well defined, pristine setup, not inheriting anything from any other session, but this is really not the case for "su" uid changes: most of the execution environment is inherited over, in numerous and non-obvious ways, for example MAC contexts, audit contexts, cgroup contexts, namespace contexts, scheduling, timer granularity,

You'll need to login as your user via the TTY, your display manager, `machinectl login` or `ssh` to get a session that is clean enough to run the systemd user bus.

If none of these make sense for your user, then perhaps your user is a system user (not intended for login).  In that case, consider using `User=` in your service instead of trying to run this on the user bus.