# dbus/systemd on a headless server

Tags: systemd, d-bus

I would like to experiment with systemd (systemctl --user) to start and stop a big application. The server where it will run is headless.

I have tried in a first terminal:

```
dbus-daemon --session --print-address 1
```

and in a second

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="..." systemctl --user show-environment
```

This cause an error in the first terminal:

```
dbus-daemon[13421]: [session uid=1001 pid=13421] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

It seems I need the systemd(1) daemon and that it complains, but why ? How to satisfy him ?
My target is RedHat, but I can reproduce the problem on ubuntu.

Comment: How did that user log in?  If you are experimenting with a mock (or system) user using `sudo -u` or `su`, then you'll have problems because `loginctl` doesn't create a fresh environment for that user.  This answer may help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615964/272848

Comment: I have tested with ssh connection. On ubuntu, I have reproduced with a simple terminal on the desktop.