# Failed to connect to bus

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

While I am trying to execute

```
systemctl --user enable rclone@gdrive
```

or

```
systemctl --user start rclone@gdrive
```

on reboot time, I am getting following error:

```
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

Comment: How and where exactly are you trying to run these commands? They indicate that dbus is not running, or you are in a context where you cannot connect to it.

Comment: That may happen when you try to use `--user`, but are in a `root` shell without the proper `systemd` context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615917/failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-connection-refused)