# Why is `systemctl --user` broken unless I run it using `su`?

Tags: linux, systemd, lubuntu, systemctl

In a recent Lubuntu 22.04 install, when running `systemctl --user` with user 1000 I get:

```
❯ systemctl status --user
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
❯ eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)
❯ systemctl status --user
Failed to read server status: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

However, when using another user (1001), or the same user, via `su $user`, `systemctl status --user` works just fine.

Data:

- When the user 1001 has an active tty session (via `su`, `ls /run/user` shows `1001` and `systemctl status user-1001.slice` shows it active.
- `journalctl -u user-1000.slice` shows no errors.
- The problem is the same for newly created users.
- Is user 1000 is 'delta', executing `su delta` (from delta's ssh session), and then `systemclt --user`, all works. Somehow, `su` creates the needed environment, but not ssh.

What else can I do to debug the problem? Can I restore systemd status config to a fresh state?, or copy something from 1002 to 1001?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR $UID $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`?  It sounds like your `sshd` is not setting up your environment.  Try `machinectl login .host` (from the `systemd-container` package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UsePAM yes` was missing from my sshd config.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from:

[Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615917/failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-connection-refused/615964#615964)

You'll get the `Failed to connect to bus` when `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is not equal to `$UID`.  This can happen if you are logged in as one user, then `su` to another user.

I suspect you are logged in as user `1000`.  Then you are `su`'d to user `1001`.  You are trying to user the `systemctl --user` bus as user `1001`, but that doesn't work until you did the `su 1000 ...` which makes `$UID` equal to `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` again.

There are probably other ways you can get into this situation.

The solution is to avoid using `su` at all.  Per the [systemd devs](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7451#issuecomment-346787237):

> "su" is a tool for changing user identities and very few other process credentials temporarily. It's not a tool for opening a completely new login session. A new login session has a very well defined, pristine setup, not inheriting anything from any other session, but this is really not the case for "su" uid changes: most of the execution environment is inherited over, in numerous and non-obvious ways, for example MAC contexts, audit contexts, cgroup contexts, namespace contexts, scheduling, timer granularity,

Instead, ensure you are logged in with a full session.  Some ways to do this:

- Open a new TTY and login
- `machinectl login` or `machinectl shell delta@.host`
- `ssh delta@127.0.0.1`
- Exit to the display manager and login again.

Comment: "This can happen if you are logged in as one user, then su to another use" --> not my case: I ssh using delta, exec `system status --user`, it fails; then I run `su delta` (from delta's ssh session), and the same command works.

Comment: in my man pages for machinectl login it says "If an argument is supplied, it refers to the container machine to connect to" - so I'm not sure `machinectl login delta` is correct.  I think instead we want `sudo machinectl shell delta@.host`.  However I'm also very new to this so I could be misunderstanding