# su : connect to another user with D-BUS activated

Tags: systemd, services, pam, d-bus

I created a user that run timers and service with `systemctl --user`. When I try to login via `ssh`, I have no issue with `systemctl --user`. But when I connect to this user with `su`, I have a bus error:

```shellsession
me@some_host / $ sudo su -l some_user -                       
some_user@some_host / $ systemctl --user status a_random.service
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

Then I tried this:

```shellsession
me@some_host / $ systemctl --machine=some_user@.host --user status a_random.service               
Cannot access user instance remotely.
```

I am running this on Debian. I think it as to do with `pam.d`but not sure. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Or maybe this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615964/272848

Comment: It did not solved this issue but it helped me in finding my own solution, so thank :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with adding custom `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` variable into my `.bashrc`

In order to do that I first identified my UID:

```
$ echo $UID
1002
```

And then I create my variable:

```
$ export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1002"
```

Adding this last command into my `.bashrc` made this persistent. And voila! :)